# Sticky Header Scroll misfunction

Tags: javascript, html

I've got following code for my Header that gets sticky if it reaches the top of the window:

```
$(function () {
    var stickyHeaderTop = $('#outer-header').offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop) {
            $('#outer-header').css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: '-300px'
            });
        } else {
            $('#outer-header').css({
                position: 'static',
                top: '0px'
            });
        }
    });
});
```

It works, but as it reaches the top and gets sticky the content scrolls the normal scroll + the height of the div that was over the Header.(so it makes a too big jump that doesn't look smooth)

Comment: Of course this happens, because `#outer-header` does not influence the rest of the page layout when it is set to `fixed` – but it starts to do once you change it to `static`. You should switch between `fixed` and `absolute` to avoid this. (Might require a few more modifications.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to CBroe for his hint!
This is a working solution:

```
$(function () {
    var stickyHeaderTop = $('#outer-header').offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= stickyHeaderTop) {
            $('#outer-header').css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: '-300px'
            });
            $('#main').css({
                position: 'relative',
                top: '332px'
            });
        } else {
            $('#outer-header').css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: '0px'
            });
            $('#main').css({
                position: 'relative',
                top: '332px'
            });
        }
    });
});
```